# LightSwitch-Like ASP.NET Application Framework

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-lightswitch, application-framework

I have built several ASP.NET web applications in the past but have always struggled to get the application's basic structure in place.  Building a framework using a combination of Silverlight/RIA services (or LightSwitch) is quite easy, but this makes your application not accessible through browsers that do not support Silverlight.

Is there any ASP.NET application framework with an HTML UI that provides the basic services that lightswitch provides?

By basic services I mean:

1. User Management
2. Themes
3. Standard way of displaying/editing basic records and master/detail records

Answer (score 1):

see:
[Integrating Visual Studio LightSwitch Application Into An Existing Website using IFrames](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/LightSwitch/DNNThingsForSale.aspx)

Comment: Silverlight is not supported on iOS devices. I need a solution that does not rely on Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.evolutility.org/ or http://www.rapidwebdev.org/, both are opensource.